# Probability of defective factory tools

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

I tried Bayes Theorem and tree diagram. I end up having more than one unknown. Kindly help.
Q. Calculate the probability that an element drawn from elements produced in the factory is the first
quality product, if it is known that 5% of the total production are defective elements, and 80% non-
defective elements are the first quality elements.

Answer (score 0):

If you draw an element, the probability that it is not defective is $0.95$. So, the probability of a not defective item is the first quality $Pr(first-quaity|not-defective)=0.8$ so the total probability is: $Pr(first-quaity)=0.8*0.95$

Comment: Oh, that's perfect. Thank you very much